# Looking for the source of expository passages concerning the Adams spectral sequence

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

The following question might be off-topic strictly speaking, but it does have the form of a reference request (in some sense) and also I think that enough members of the relevant community are MO users that one could get a decent answer.

I happened to be looking at the [Wikipedia page for the Adams spectral sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adams_spectral_sequence). On reading the "Motivation" section, I am struck by a powerful sense of *déjà vu* — it really feels like I have seen this text, almost verbatim, somewhere else. Certain phrases like "this is extraordinarily ambitious" and "the gain is enormous" feel like the voice of a singular author with a dramatic inclination, and not typical of the style I associate with Wikipedia entries.

Does anyone happen to recognise these passages from some other text? I would ideally like confirmation with a particular reference, so this is not meant to be a subjective question.

Comment: For the record: I'm referring to the version with timestamp "24 October 2022, at 04:56 (UTC)"

Comment: FWIW this user added it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/98.218.198.248